# How to move Borderless DhtmlDialog with other click events

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I am moving Borderless DHtmlDialog of MFC with this method:

```
BOOL CMyDlg::preTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
     if(pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
     {
          PostMessage( WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, MAKELPARAM( pMsg->pt.x, pMsg->pt.y));
          return false;
     }
       return CDHtmlDialog::preTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

But the problem is that it is moving but couldn't picking up any click event for tags and ids given in `DHTML_EVENT_MAP`.

Can any one please guide what is the main problem in this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `DHTML_EVENT_MAP` will not handle click events on tags. 
MFC macros are not supposed to do that. You will need event sink in your code.

Refer [Handling HTML Element Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508508%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)